# Sequelize include objects with scope 1:m constraint = false

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I want to use same table `Photo` for other tables.
I read Sequelize doc [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#1-m)
they use scope and set constraint = false like this

```html
const Comment = this.sequelize.define('comment', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  commentable: Sequelize.STRING,
  commentable_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

Comment.prototype.getItem = function(options) {
  return this['get' + this.get('commentable').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.get('commentable').substr(1)](options);
};

Post.hasMany(this.Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
  constraints: false,
  scope: {
    commentable: 'post'
  }
});
Comment.belongsTo(this.Post, {
  foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
  constraints: false,
  as: 'post'
});
```

my question is: HOW I can query list of Post that include list comments for each post (with limit if it's avaiable).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HOW I can query list of Post that include list comments for each post

Here, try this

```
Post
  .find({
    where: { /* include where condition if you have or remove this */ },
    include: [{
      model: Comment,
      as: 'comments',
    }],
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // check result.dataValues. it should contain `comments` array
  });
```

The limit is not yet available i suppose. check this for updates
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1897

Comment: can you try again @RobertPham? I updated with `promise` use

Comment: Do we need this:
Comment.prototype.getItem = function(options) {
  return this['get' + this.get('commentable').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.get('commentable').substr(1)](options);
};

Comment: I think I missed this instance function when doing query, modify this function make it work. Thanks

Comment: ok glad it worked. also, does this work? `Post.hasMany(this.Comment, {` you might want to remove `this.` as well so it looks like this `Post.hasMany(Comment`